# Displaying insignificant figures in a console with integers

Tags: c++, console, integer, iostream

I have a program that displays songs read in from a text file along with the time and displays them in a neat organized manner in the console. I'm having trouble however having an **integer** display `01` or `06` as opposed to `1` or `6` for my time format (00:00:00). How would i go about manipulating the output to display a zero infront of the integer when it is below 10?

An example output from my program:

```
SONG TITLE
The once and future carpenter      0:4:52
I never knew you                   0:7:48
Life                               0:10:52
February seven                     0:15:0
My lfe                             0:24:12
Yuor frei                          0:37:20
Lisjlf                             0:49:23
Lasifj                             0:53:39
Longsong                           1:9:2
Longer                             1:22:3
Almost done                        1:34:48

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.280 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Desired Output:

```
SONG TITLE
The once and future carpenter      00:04:52
I never knew you                   00:07:48
Life                               00:10:52
February seven                     00:15:00
My lfe                             00:24:12
Yuor frei                          00:37:20
Lisjlf                             00:49:23
Lasifj                             00:53:39
Longsong                           01:09:02
Longer                             01:22:03
Almost done                        01:34:48

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.280 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And how do you display your values? Using stream utilities provided by standard library? if so, you could use `setw` manipulator in conjunction with `setfill`. `stdio` counterparts also allow specifying of widht and fill, using appropriate flags with format specifier:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

...
cout << setw(2) << setfill('0') << h << ':' 
    << setw(2) << setfill('0') << m << ':' 
    << setw(2) << setfill('0') << s << '\n';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%02d:%02d:%02\n", h, m, s);
```

Comment: i'd prefer the C++ solution over the C solution, but i'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Oh, C++? `std::printf("%02d:%02d:%02\n", h, m, s);` then.

Comment: I prefer this over all solutions since it's the most simple one as well as efficient.